# Python: Write a dataframe to an already existing excel which contains a sheet with images

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on this for too long now. I have an Excel with one sheet (sheetname = 'abc') with images in it and I want to have a Python script that writes a dataframe on a second separate sheet (sheetname = 'def') in the same excel file. Can anybody provide me with some example code, because everytime I try to write the dataframe, the first sheet with the images gets emptied.

This is what I tried:

```
book = load_workbook('filename_of_file_with_pictures_in_it.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename_of_file_with_pictures_in_it.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

x1 = np.random.randn(100, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(x1)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'def')
writer.save()
book.close()
```

It saves the random numbers in the sheet with the name 'def', but the first sheet 'abc' now becomes empty.

What goes wrong here? Hopefully somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question! With openpyxl you can easily add values, keep the formulas but cannot retain the graphs. Also with the latest version (2.5.4), graphs do not stay. So, I decided to address the issue with 
[xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org) :

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(r"filename_of_file_with_pictures_in_it.xlsx")
sht=wb.sheets.add('SheetMod')
sht.range('A1').value = np.random.randn(100, 2)
wb.save(r"path_new_file.xlsx")
```

With this snippet I managed to insert the random set of values and saved a new copy of the modified xlsx.As you insert the command, the excel file will automatically open showing you the new sheet- without changing the existing ones (graphs and formulas included). Make sure you install all the interdependencies to get xlwings to run in your system. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an Excel 'reader' like Openpyxl or similar in combnination with Pandas for this, pandas' to_excel function is write only so it will not care what is inside the file when you open it.

Comment: I already use Openpyxl within the following line, right?: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename_of_file_with_pictures_in_it.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl').
Do you have an example of how to solve it the way you are saying.

Comment: You did, but you're using Openpyxl's 'writing' engine in conjunction with Pandas' ExcelWriter function, there is no reading involved. Openpyxl handles both reading and writing. I don't have code to hand that solves the issue but you would most certainly need to read the excel file before doing anything or your data will be lost.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought load_workbook is the reading function of openpyxl. So if i load it like that, how can it be that the images are lost.

Comment: If I use the following code then I still got the same problem (the text is there, but the images are gone).

    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = load_workbook('filename_of_file_with_pictures_in_it.xlsx')

    # grab the active worksheet
    ws = wb['abc']

    # Data can be assigned directly to cellsws['A2'] = 'lalala'
    ws['B2'] = 123

    ws['A3'] = 'lololo'
    ws['B3'] = 456

    # Save the file
    wb.save('filename_of_file_with_pictures_in_it.xlsx')